# how to creat a image with vertical and horizontal line opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

i am working on a project where i need a reference image [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pLyg.jpg)

say if want to create a image using Opencv with particular -width -hight

and certain number for horizontal(x) & vertical(y) line to be created evenly

Comment: which programing language? c++? python?

Comment: Have you at least tried something? Or read opencv docunentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an image of a particular size using the Mat constructor:

> cv::Mat::Mat  (   Size    size,       int     type    )
>
> This is an overloaded member function, provided for convenience. It
>   differs from the above function only in what argument(s) it accepts.
>
> Parameters
>       size  2D array size: Size(cols, rows) . In the Size() constructor, the number of rows and the number of columns go in the reverse order.
>       type  Array type. Use CV_8UC1, ..., CV_64FC4 to create 1-4 channel matrices, or CV_8UC(n), ..., CV_64FC(n) to create multi-channel (up to
>   CV_CN_MAX channels) matrices.

and you can draw lines on images (Mats) using the line method:

```
 C++: void line(Mat& img, Point pt1, Point pt2, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0)
```

Some example code to create an image with a line in would be:

```
cv::Mat myImage=cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(10,10), CV_8UC1);
line(myImage, cv::Point(5,5), cv::point(10,10), cv::Scalar::all(255));
```